# Web-scraping data from pages with forms

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new in web-scraping and I want to get the data of this webpage: http://www.neotroptree.info/data/countrysearch

In this link, we see four fields (Country, Domain, State, and Site).

[image: site]

I have a data frame with the site names, which I did scrape using the following code:

```r
ipak <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg))
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

ipak(c("rgdal", "tidyverse"))
#> Loading required package: rgdal
#> Loading required package: sp
#> rgdal: version: 1.3-4, (SVN revision 766)
#>  Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
#>  Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.2, released 2017/09/15
#>  Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/2.2
#>  GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE
#>  Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
#>  Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
#>  Linking to sp version: 1.3-1
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
#>     rgdal tidyverse
#>      TRUE      TRUE

download.file(url = "http://www.neotroptree.info/files/Neotropicos.kmz", 
              destfile = "neotroptree-site.kmz", 
              quiet = FALSE)

rgdal::ogrListLayers("neotroptree-site.kmz")
#> [1] "Neotropicos"
#> [2] "Jubones, Quito, Pichincha, Ecuador"
#> attr(,"driver")
#> [1] "LIBKML"
#> attr(,"nlayers")
#> [1] 2

ntt <- rgdal::readOGR("neotroptree-site.kmz", "Neotropicos")
#> OGR data source with driver: LIBKML
#> Source: "/tmp/Rtmppf54qE/neotroptree-site.kmz", layer: "Neotropicos"
#> with 7504 features
#> It has 11 fields

ntt.df <- data.frame(site = ntt@data$Name,
                     long = ntt@coords[, 1],
                     lat = ntt@coords[, 2]) %>%
  .[order(.$site), ] %>%
  mutate(., ID = rownames(.)) %>%
  mutate(., site = as.character(site))

ntt.df <- ntt.df[, c("ID", "site", "long", "lat")]

glimpse(ntt.df)
#> Observations: 7,504
#> Variables: 4
#> $ ID   <chr> "2618", "2612", "3229", "2717", "2634", "4907", "3940", "...
#> $ site <chr> "Abadia, cerrado", "Abadia, floresta semidecidual", "Abad...
#> $ long <dbl> -43.15000, -43.10667, -48.72250, -45.52493, -45.27417, -4...
#> $ lat  <dbl> -17.690000, -17.676944, -16.089167, -19.111667, -19.26638...
```

Manually, I need:

1. Fill the "Site" field with each name from the site column of the data frame, get the results, and proceed to "Site details" link

[image]

2. Get data from "Download site details" link.

[image]

My first try was using the `rvest` package, but it was not able to find the forms field inside the webpage.

```r
if(!require("rvest")) install.packages("rvest")
#> Loading required package: rvest
#> Loading required package: xml2

url <- "http://www.neotroptree.info/data/countrysearch"
webpage <- html_session(url)
webpage %>%
  html_form()
#> list()
```

Any thoughts of how iterate this process?

Comment: Since you are required to select both the site details and download button, I would suggest using RSelenium.

Comment: RSelenium is some serious overkill for this IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSelenium, [`decapitated`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/decapitated) and [`splashr`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) all introduce third-party dependencies which can be difficult to setup and maintain.

No browser instrumentation is required here so no need for RSelenium. `decapitated` won't really help much either and `splashr` is a bit overkill for this use-case.

The form you see on the site is a proxy to a Solr database. Open up Developer Tools on your browser on that URL hit refresh and look at the XHR section of the Network section. You'll see it makes asynchronous requests on load and with each form interaction.

All we have to do is mimic those interactions. The source below is *heavily* annotated and you might want to step through them manually to see what's going on under the hood.

We'll need some helpers:

```
library(xml2)
library(curl)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
```

Most of ^^ get loaded anyway when you load `rvest` but I like being explicit. Also, `stringr` is an unnecessary crutch for the far more explicit-in-operation named `stringi` functions, so we'll use them.

First, we get the list of sites. This function mimics the `POST` request you hopefully saw when you took the advice to use Developer Tools to see what's going on:

```
get_list_of_sites <- function() {

  # This is the POST reques the site makes to get the metdata for the popups.
  # I used http://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter to untangle the monstosity
  httr::POST(
    url = "http://www.neotroptree.info/data/sys/scripts/solrform/solrproxy.php",
    body = list(
      q = "*%3A*",
      host = "padme.rbge.org.uk",
      c = "neotroptree",
      template = "countries.tpl",
      datasetid = "",
      f = "facet.field%3Dcountry_s%26facet.field%3Dstate_s%26facet.field%3Ddomain_s%26facet.field%3Dsitename_s"
    ),
    encode = "form"
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  # extract the returned JSON from the HTML document it returns
  xdat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(html_text(content(res, encoding="UTF-8")))

  # only return the site list (the xdat structure had alot more in it tho)
  discard(xdat$facets$sitename_s, stri_detect_regex, "^[[:digit:]]+$")

}
```

We'll call that below but it just returns a character vector of site names.

Now we need a function to get the site data returned in the lower portion of the form output. This is doing the same thing as above except it adds in the ability to take a site to download and where it should store the file. `overwrite` is handy since you may be doing alot of downloads and try to download the same file again. Since we're using `httr::write_disk()` to save the file, setting this parameter to `FALSE` will cause an exception and stop any loop/iteration you've got. You likely don't want that.

```
get_site <- function(site, dl_path, overwrite=TRUE) {

  # this is the POST request the site makes as an XHR request so we just
  # mimic it with httr::POST. We pass in the site code in `q`

  httr::POST(
    url = "http://www.neotroptree.info/data/sys/scripts/solrform/solrproxy.php",
    body = list(
      q = sprintf('sitename_s:"%s"', curl::curl_escape(site)),
      host = "padme.rbge.org.uk",
      c = "neotroptree",
      template = "countries.tpl",
      datasetid = "",
      f = "facet.field%3Dcountry_s%26facet.field%3Dstate_s%26facet.field%3Ddomain_s%26facet.field%3Dsitename_s"
    ),
    encode = "form"
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  # it returns a JSON structure 
  xdat <- httr::content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
  xdat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(xdat)

  # unfortunately the bit with the site-id is in HTML O_o
  # so we have to parse that bit out of the returned JSON
  site_meta <- xml2::read_html(xdat$docs)

  # now, extract the link code
  link <- html_attr(html_node(site_meta, "div.solrlink"), "data-linkparams")
  link <- stri_replace_first_regex(link, "code_s:", "")

  # Download the file and get the filename metadata back
  xret <- get_link(link, dl_path) # the code for this is below

  # add the site name
  xret$site <- site

  # return the list
  xret[c("code", "site", "path")]

}
```

I put the code for retrieving the file into a separate function since it seemed to make sense to encapsulate this functionality into a separate function. YMMV. I took the liberty of removing the nonsensical `,` in filenames as well.

```
get_link <- function(code, dl_path, overwrite=TRUE) {

  # The Download link looks like this:
  #
  # <a href="http://www.neotroptree.info/projectfiles/downloadsitedetails.php?siteid=AtlMG104">
  #   Download site details.
  # </a>
  #
  # So we can mimic that with httr

  site_tmpl <- "http://www.neotroptree.info/projectfiles/downloadsitedetails.php?siteid=%s"
  dl_url <- sprintf(site_tmpl, code)

  # The filename comes in a "Content-Disposition" header so we first
  # do a lightweight HEAD request to get the filename

  res <- httr::HEAD(dl_url)
  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  stri_replace_all_regex(
    res$headers["content-disposition"],
    '^attachment; filename="|"$', ""
  ) -> fil_name

  # commas in filenames are a bad idea rly
  fil_name <- stri_replace_all_fixed(fil_name, ",", "-")

  message("Saving ", code, " to ", file.path(dl_path, fil_name))

  # Then we use httr::write_disk() to do the saving in a full GET request
  res <- httr::GET(
    url = dl_url,
    httr::write_disk(
      path = file.path(dl_path, fil_name),
      overwrite = overwrite
    )
  )

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  # return a list so we can make a data frame
  list(
    code = code,
    path = file.path(dl_path, fil_name)
  )

}
```

Now, we get the list of sites (as promised):

```
# get the site list
sites <- get_list_of_sites()

length(sites)
## [1] 7484

head(sites)
## [1] "Abadia, cerrado"                                     
## [2] "Abadia, floresta semidecídua"                        
## [3] "Abadiânia, cerrado"                                  
## [4] "Abaetetuba, Rio Urubueua, floresta inundável de maré"
## [5] "Abaeté, cerrado"                                     
## [6] "Abaeté, floresta ripícola"
```

We'll grab one site ZIP file:

```
# get one site link dl
get_site(sites[1], "/tmp")
## $code
## [1] "CerMG044"
## 
## $site
## [1] "Abadia, cerrado"
## 
## $path
## [1] "/tmp/neotroptree-CerMG04426-09-2018.zip"
```

Now, get a few more and return a data frame with code, site and save path:

```
# get a few (remomove [1:2] to do them all but PLEASE ADD A Sys.sleep(5) into get_link() if you do!)
map_df(sites[1:2], get_site, dl_path = "/tmp")
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   code     site                         path                              
##   <chr>    <chr>                        <chr>                             
## 1 CerMG044 Abadia, cerrado              /tmp/neotroptree-CerMG04426-09-20…
## 2 AtlMG104 Abadia, floresta semidecídua /tmp/neotroptree-AtlMG10426-09-20…
```

Please heed the guidance to add a `Sys.sleep(5)` into `get_link()` if you're going to do a mass download. CPU, memory and bandwidth aren't free and it's likely that site didn't really scale the server to meet a barrage of ~8,000 back-to-back multi-HTTP request call sequence with file downloads at the end of them.

Comment: Stellar solution! It worked like a charm! Be sure I'll follow your guidance about the mass download. Maybe this isn't suitable here, but: many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

@hrbrmstr Folowing your guide I could do it with python. I was struggling with selenium.
 Also I added a log to be easier to start again from the middle, and a recursive loop to download the file, retrying while the error persists, which is good to ensure all sites will be in the result, of course, intending to completely copy the database. 
Here is the code just in case someone would like to know how it is in python

```
import requests
import os
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call

out_dir = '/home/rupestre/tree_scrap/data/'

def read_log(out_dir):
    log_path = os.path.join(out_dir,'log.txt')
    site_names = []
    if os.path.isfile(log_path):
        with open(log_path) as log:
            for line in log:
                site_names.append(line.strip())
    return site_names

def save_log(site_name,out_dir):
    log_path = os.path.join(out_dir,'log.txt')
    call('echo "{}\n" >> {}'.format(site_name,log_path),shell=True)

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

def get_sites():
    url = "http://www.neotroptree.info/data/sys/scripts/solrform/solrproxy.php"
    data = {
          'q' : "*%3A*",
          'host' : "padme.rbge.org.uk",
          'c' : "neotroptree",
          'template' : "countries.tpl",
          'datasetid' : "",
          'f' : "facet.field%3Dcountry_s%26facet.field%3Dstate_s%26facet.field%3Ddomain_s%26facet.field%3Dsitename_s"
        }
    x = requests.post(url,data,headers={'accept': 'application/json'})
    response = x.json()
    sites = response['facets']['sitename_s']
    sites = [x for x in sites if x != 1]
    return sites

def get_site_code(site):
    data = {
          'q' : 'sitename_s:"{}"'.format(site),
          'host' : "padme.rbge.org.uk",
          'c' : "neotroptree",
          'template' : "countries.tpl",
          'datasetid' : "",
          'f' : "facet.field%3Dcountry_s%26facet.field%3Dstate_s%26facet.field%3Ddomain_s%26facet.field%3Dsitename_s"
        }
    url = "http://www.neotroptree.info/data/sys/scripts/solrform/solrproxy.php"
    x = requests.post(url,data,headers={'accept': 'application/json'})
    #print(x.status_code)
    response = x.json()
    site_data = response['docs']
    site_code = site_data.split("data-linkparams=")[1].split('"')[1].split('code_s:')[1]
    return site_code

def get_filename(site_code):
    url_code = "http://www.neotroptree.info/projectfiles/downloadsitedetails.php?siteid={}".format(site_code)
    x = requests.head(url_code)
    filename = x.headers['Content-Disposition'].split('"')[-2]
    return filename,url_code

def main():
    log = read_log(out_dir)
    sites = get_sites()
    for site in sites:
        if site in log:
            continue
        download = False
        while not download:
            try:
                print(site)
                site_code = get_site_code(site)
                filename,url_code = get_filename(site_code)
                local_file = os.path.join(out_dir,filename)
                if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
                    download_url(url_code,local_file)
                    save_log(site,out_dir)
                    download=True
                    print(filename)
                    sleep(5)
                else:
                    save_log(site,out_dir)
                    download=True
                    print(filename)
                    sleep(5)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```